# Haskell: Non-exhaustive patterns in factorial function

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, ghci

I've tried implementing a recursive factorial function in GHCi, but I'm receiving the following error:

```
Prelude> fact n = n * fact (n-1)
Prelude> fact 0 = 1
Prelude> fact 1
*** Exception: <interactive>:2:1-10: Non-exhaustive patterns in function fact
```

Where is this coming from, and how can I avoid this mistake in the future?

Comment: Does this still happen if you write it in a file/outside of GHCI? Nothing stands out to me.

Comment: There is a duplicate for this somewhere, but essentially you haven't provided two cases for a single `fact` function; GHCi 8 lets you drop the `let` from function definitions now, so you really defined one function defined for any argument, then *replaced* it with a function defined only for 0.

Comment: You probably wouldn't make this mistake in earlier versions of GHCi; an assignment without `let` would be an error, and you probably wouldn't mistake `let fact n = ...` followed by `let fact 0 = 1` as parts of the same definition.

Comment: @chepner, I think not *quite* a duplicate because of the syntax relaxation.

Comment: @dfeuer Yeah, I wanted to use the question where we've discussed GHC8 specifically, but I can't find it  :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As people have pointed out in the comments, a definition on a single line in GHCi 8 replaces any previous definition.  If you want to enter a multi-pattern definition, you need to use the special `:{` and `:}` codes to start and end a multi-line command.  So, the following works fine:

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| fact 0 = 1
Prelude| fact n = n * fact (n-1)
Prelude| :}
Prelude> fact 10
3628800
Prelude>
```

(Note that this is applicable to GHCi 8 only, not 7.)

Also, mind the order in your definition.  In Haskell, order of patterns matters, so if you try to match `fact n` first, it will always match, so your `fact 0` pattern will never be used..

Edit:  For GHCI 7, you need to use the `let` syntax with appropriate indentation to enter a multi-pattern definition:

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| let fact 0 = 1
Prelude|     fact n = n * fact (n-1)
Prelude| :}
Prelude> fact 10
3628800
Prelude>
```

Comment: The multi-line syntax is the same. The improvement is that definitions don't need `let` anymore, which was especially obnoxious for multi-line definitions.